# ImageMagick: Promote grays to CMYK black?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

Is there a way to move all gray colors of a CMYK image (e.g. a CMYK .tiff) into the black (K) plate with ImageMagick?

(In Adobe Acrobat Pro, this functionality is labeled: "Promote grays to CMYK black")

Here's an image to experiment with: [image: Example Image]

You can view an example of this process on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model#Benefits_of_using_black_ink).

Comment: If you add an image to test on, I will try and work out an answer.

Comment: Thank you for updating your post. I have had a read and I presume you are referring to Gray Component Replacement (GCR) as detailed here... http://cmc.printing.org/how-color-separation-with-gcr-gives-you-more-consistent-color/ Before I do too much work, is that what you mean? Also, if GCR is what you seek, do you mean 100% GCR or say 50% as specified in the example?

Comment: Also, the image above is a JPEG in sRGB colorspace, not a CMYK TIFF.

Answer (score 1):

Also not a full answer as such, but hopefully useful towards producing one - by Kurt, myself or others. I looked at the Photoshop method of GCR and am adding the characteristic curves that Adobe seem to use for GCR. There are 5 levels, ranging from "None", through "Light", "Medium", "Heavy" and "Full".

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I presume the "Light" curve is showing that no black ink is added into the mix till it would be over 50%, and the "Medium" shows the black would have to be only 25% before any gets added, and the "Heavy" shows that only 12-15% of black is needed before black ink gets added into the mixture.

I also add the following reference to assist any other answerers... [see PDF here](http://cias.rit.edu/~gravure/tt/pdf/cm/TT3_1_Ryan.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that the provided example image is ***NOT*** a TIFF (as announced), and does ***NOT*** use a CMYK color space (as announced), but is a JPEG using sRGB, here is how you would convert it into a TIFF file using CMYK, where the black channel is used:

```
 convert                               \
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFnCz.jpg \
   -colorspace cmy                     \
   -colorspace cmyk                    \
    cmyk.tiff
```

To separate out the different colors again and show them as grayscale images each, use these commands:

```
 convert HFnCz.tiff -colorspace cmyk -channel c         -separate channel_c.png
 convert HFnCz.tiff -colorspace cmyk -channel m         -separate channel_m.png
 convert HFnCz.tiff -colorspace cmyk -channel y         -separate channel_y.png
 convert HFnCz.tiff -colorspace cmyk -channel k -negate -separate channel_k.png
```

I did output to PNG in order to keep the file size a bit smaller...

Here are the 4 color separations. Top left is C, top right is M, bottom left is Y, bottom right is K:

[image: Top left is Cyan, top right is Magenta, bottom left is Yellow, bottom right is blacK]

### Update

I made a mistake in my original answer. The `-negate` command parameter should only be there for the `blacK` channel.

Comment: Hello Kurt. Do you believe this to fully answer the OP's request to "move all grays to the black plate"? Or are you suggesting this is a starting point for further processing?

Comment: This may only be a starting point for further *discussion*. Because to '***move***' all grays is not possible, when there are no grays in the original (which is RGB) in the first place! What you can do is '***convert***' for each pixel, equal amounts of R, G and B values to respective values of K (either fully, or a certain amount...).

Comment: Good! We are on the same page :-)